# Data Transfer between Mobile Phones Across Connected Voice Call

Tags: android, mobile-phones, data-transfer, analog-digital-converter

I require a fast reliable method of sending control commands (simple data, possibly only a few dozen possible commands) to a remote system which is using a smartphone* as its onboard computer.  I have deemed standard data packages used for mobile internet data transfer as too unreliable of control purposes, however I have noticed that once a voice call is initiated it is much more reliable.  Has there been any development into sending data between phones across a connected call, and if not are there any known reasons a modified dialup modem in software form couldn't be used?

Furthermore, could this protocol be robust enough to send back low res video and other simple numeric data?

*Smartphone - A phone with significant processing power and ability to run custom programs (most likely with an Android based OS however am open to suggestions)

Comment: Not many standard Android devices allow you to record the audio from the phone call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370278/record-phone-calls-on-android-phone

But, it sounds like you might be able to leverage custom hardware rather than standard handsets, which will be necessary. Then you should be able to devise an audio-channel encoding scheme that isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SMS? while you won't get video data it may work for small chunks of data. Also if the small chunks are from the phone to a server, you may try sending DTMF down the line (however I've yet to see that working.
Other than that it's customised hardware.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342236/sending-dtmf-tones-over-the-uplink-in-call re DTMF

Comment: I guess however if your writing a custom app, you could play with the OS Code and remove the limitations noted in the above link. However doing so it way beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...this reminds me of those old TV games like Hugo...there you had a voice connection and I think the commands were given by the different tone of the key pressed from 0-9. Maybe you should try something similar.