# How to send dtmf tones from my application to outgoing call?

Tags: android

I have developed android application which call the other person on button click, but now i want to send dtmf tones from application to that outgoing call when ever i need. so how to do that?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: yes, already Implemented and works fine :)

Comment: can you please share code with me? here is my email: pro100svitlo@gmail.com

Comment: lets talk on Skype : aniket.shinde2412

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible. It's not so obvious and not so elegant. But it works :)
In my project I requested permission for accessibility service. It gives me possibility to programmatically emulate clicks on the screen. Then I get the screen coordinates for the 'open keyboard' button and all number buttons which I need to press (tones which needed to be send).
Then it's super easy - catch income call with receiver, make small delay and then run sequence of emulated clicks.

Tada

In case someone need code - I can share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send DTMF tones during an active call, but you can send them when you "program" them when you initiate the call. see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12986066/475472

Comment: Yes i have implemented while "program", but i want to send DTMF while the call is active. is it impossible to do that?

Comment: No,it is not possible ,you can't send any tone during call.

Comment: Any external library that we can use for this?

Comment: If you are playing any tone during call the call will end up.

Comment: Actually what is your exact requirement,the receiver end want to hear your DTMF tone?

Comment: basically i am calling my server from my application, and the phone call is active on background of my application. so now i want send dtmf tones in active call so that server can catch them and work accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, if we can root the device and use some open source or ndk will it work??