# How the sytem app Phone send response to the dialler?

Tags: android, phone-call, dtmf

Does anybody know how the sytem phone app can send data to the dialler phone number?

For example, when bank calling your number and than voice asking you to press "1" for "this" and "second" for this, etc...

I need to do the same, but I am stuck here... Will be glad any help!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8870488/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: I have seen it. But that code didn't help enough. It's start new call, and I need just send tone within current call.

Comment: Seems it's not possible programmatically (more details [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-Android-app-to-play-music-during-a-call-so-both-the-sides-can-hear-it) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784221/how-to-play-an-audio-file-on-a-voice-call-in-android), but its possible via external device that plays DTMF (or other) tones due call.

Comment: It's deffinetly possible: that's exactly what native phone app did ;-)

Comment: Of course its possible "in general", but it's impossible via custom installed application on non-rooted device with non modified system image.

Comment: there are apps on playMarket, alternative phoneCall apps. they also can do the same :) so it's possible not only "in general"! I was to lazy, but it looks like it's time to dig with reverse engeneering...

Comment: Please take a look at "APPLICATIONS WHO CLAIM TO DO THIS!?!?!" part of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28448877/6950238) answer.