# Is it possible to programmatically dial numbers during a phone call?

Tags: android, android-dialer

I know it is possible in Android to make a dialer,

but is it possible to make the dialer "press 1" during a phone call?(like when you call support and you have to press all sort of numbers just to talk to a person)
Is there code of how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342236/sending-dtmf-tones-over-the-uplink-in-call

Answer (score 1):

thanks to simon who pointed me to [Sending DTMF tones over the uplink in-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342236/sending-dtmf-tones-over-the-uplink-in-call),

so it seems there is an app that does this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shdroid.bridgetrial&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W10 , but people don't know how to do it http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428

Answer (score 0):

Create call [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and start it by using [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

```
Intent call = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel://" + number));
startActivity(call);
```