# In-band DTMF tones

Tags: dtmf

As I understand pressing a button on your phone's keypad sends an in-band DTMF tone to the other party. This is not actually sending a telephone signal of any sort, just sends the respective DTMF sound over the voice path.

When an IVR prompts me for entering DTMF tones - instead of pressing a button on the phone, what if I played pre-recorded .WAV files containing the DTMF sounds real loud at my end? Assume these files have excellent quality audio in them.

Is that technically the same thing? Can it be expected to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending DTMF tones over the uplink in-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342236/sending-dtmf-tones-over-the-uplink-in-call)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about telephony, not programming

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work fine.  If you could hum accurately enough, that would work too, but I wouldn't recommend it!